# How do I edit a 'read only' file in 12.04 Desktop?

Tags: 12.04, gksu

I want to edit a file in 12.04 desktop.  Previously (in Lucid) I could right click, select 'open with', and type in 'gksudo gedit' - which was then added to the list of available 'open with' programs.  This functionality has completely disappeared in 12.04 - or am I missing something?

I know I can fire up a terminal and type it in there - but this is supposed to be user friendly, not going back to the bad old days.  I may as well use 'sudo nano'!

Regards
John

Comment: gksudo may be missing from the install?

Answer (score 2):

Add the trick to your nautilus shortcuts:

```
wget http://www.liberiangeek.net/blog/tools/libnautilus-gksu.so
sudo cp libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/
```

Upon next restart, you should fidn "Open as Administrator" in all your right click menus.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click a file on the desktop, the Context Menu in Ubuntu 12.04 contains an option where it reads `Open with other application...`, selecting it, you have the: `use a custom command` that enables you to perform what you're used to do.